# Why is my app so slow in searching process

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to program a desktop program in Python and a database of sql lite type to search through a 4 GB database for more than 1000 ids, but the program needs two hours to search for that number, how can I make it be faster than that in searching

```
def search(self):
        try:
            database = self.mainwin.comboBox_2.currentText()
            method = self.mainwin.comboBox.currentText()
            value = self.mainwin.textEdit.toPlainText()
            value = value.split('\n')
            
            i = 0
            for x in range(0,len(value)):
                if value[x] == '':
                    i += 1
            for x in range(0,i):
                value.remove('')                     

            conn = sqlite3.connect('{0}.db'.format(database))
            cur = conn.cursor()
            get_column_names=cur.execute("select * from facebookusers limit 1")
            col_name=[i[0] for i in get_column_names.description]
            self.mainwin.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
            self.mainwin.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
            for i in range(len(col_name)):
                self.mainwin.tableWidget.insertColumn(i)
            for i in range(len(col_name)):
                col_name[i] = col_name[i].capitalize()
            self.mainwin.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(col_name)
            flag = True
            droped_ids = []
            for i in value :
                cur.execute('SELECT * FROM facebookusers WHERE {0} = ? GROUP BY {1}'.format(method,method),(i,))
                try:
                    row = cur.fetchall()
                    if len(row) == 0 :
                        droped_ids.append(i)
                    else:
                        for d in row:
                            row_count = self.mainwin.tableWidget.rowCount()
                            self.mainwin.tableWidget.insertRow(row_count)
                            self.mainwin.tableWidget.setRowHeight(row_count,50)
                            for r in range(len(col_name)):     
                                self.mainwin.tableWidget.setItem(row_count,r, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(d[r])))
                            self.mainwin.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
                            self.mainwin.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)             
                except :
                    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self,'error','error')
            if len(droped_ids) > 0 :
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self,'error','couldn\'t find these IDs {0}'.format(droped_ids))
            conn.close()
        except Exception as e:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self,'warning','please select method and database')
            print(str(e)) 
            flag = False 
        if flag:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self,'information','Search finished successfully')
```

Comment: first you could measure which part of code is slow. You can use module `time` or use `profiler` in some `IDE`. You may also try to use different database - ie. MySQL, Progress. OR use database on server provided by Google, Amazon, IBM, etc. Also GUI may slow you down. You could first get all data from database and later add result sot GUI. Eventually you could use `executemany(..., value)` to run many queries at once.

Comment: you could also add `method` to SQL query only once

Comment: You need to figure out if it's really the DB query or something else in your software. Using a SQLite interactive shell, try running variations of the SELECT statement (you don't show how your 'method' variable is set) and see how that performs

Comment: What are the requirements for the search? It looks like you’re running a query per column to find a value in that column. Some of your columns are not going to be indexed so you’ll be doing scans of the whole table, you’re likely doing that multiple times. Your question suggestions you actually want to search on an ID value, this should just be one column so instead of looping every column just write one query filtering on that one column. Make sure the ID column is indexed.